# What's more efficient/ cheaper, casting or a method call?

Tags: java, performance, casting, type-conversion

I have a `Double` that I want to knock the extra digits after the decimal place off of (I'm not too concerned about accuracy but feel free to mention it in your answer) prior to conversion into a `String`.

I was wondering whether it would be better to cast to an `int` or to use a `DecimalFormat` and call `format(..)` . Also, is it then more efficient to specify `String.valueOf()` or leave it as it is and let the compiler figure it out?

Sorry if I sound a bit ignorant, I'm genuinely curious to learn more of the technical details.

For reference, i'm drawing text to and android canvas:

```
c.drawText("FPS: " + String.valueOf((int)lastFps), xPos, yPos, paint);
```

Comment: Make a loop which do this million times and compare the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a program that used System.nanoTime() to calculate the execution time of these two methods:

```
    public static void cast() {
    for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
        int x= (int)Math.random();
    }
}

public static void format() {
    for (int i=0; i< 1000000; i++) {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
        df.format(Math.random());
    }
}
```

Here are the respective results:

80984944

6048075593

Granted my tests probably aren't perfect examples. I'm just using math.random(), which generates a number that will always cast to 0, which might affect results. However, these results do make sense - casting should be cheap, since it likely doesn't operate on the bits at all - the JVM just treats the bits differently.

Edit: If I pull out the instantiation of the formatter for the second example, the program runs in 3155165182ns. If I multiply the random numbers by Integer.MAX_VALUE in both cases (with the instantiation pulled out), the results are: 82100170 and 4174558079. Looks like casting is the way to go.

Comment: Also if the decimal format's always the same you could probably get a more accurate read by pulling the instantiation out of the for-loop.

Comment: Multiple the random result by a large number like `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and then you'll have a fairer comparison

Comment: Excellent point on pulling out the instantiation. My reasoning was the question was "which process is faster" and since the instantiation is necessary for the process, I included it. However, since it will always be the same formatter, and optimizations only really matter when you repeat them many times, it makes sense to pull it out. When doing that, the program ran in 3155165182 nanoseconds - still well behind casting.

Comment: Apreciated all answers but you and MattiasSp both took the time to run some tests and you answered first. I should have run them myself really but i thought it might be common knowledge :p cheers

Answer (score 3):

Casting will probably be more efficient. This is implemented as native code while using a method will have to go through the java code. Also it's much more readable.

For the string.valueof, I expect the performance to be strictly the same. I find it more readable to just do `"string" + intValue` than `"string" + String.valueof(intValue)`

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `Math.floor().`

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, function/method calls come at the cost of performance overhead. My vote is that typecasting would be faster, but as @Zefiryn suggested, the best way is to create a loop and do each action a multitude of times and measure the performance with a timer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the efficiency of either, but here's a third option that could be interesting to compare:

```
String.valueOf(doubleValue).substring(0, endInt)
```

which would give a set number of characters rather than decimals/numbers, and would skip the typecasting but make two function calls instead.

EDIT: Was too curious so I tried running each option:

```
integerNumberFormat.format(number)
String.valueOf(doubleValue).substring(0, endInt)
String.valueOf((int)doubleValue)
```

10^6 cycles with the results being ~800 ms, ~300 ms and ~40 ms, respectively. I guess my results won't be immediately translatable to your situation but they could give a hint that the last one is indeed, as the previous posters suggested, the fastest one.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to test! The substring use was an interesting approach too!